# For number field $K$, is maximal order $O_K$ flat over the order $O$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, flatness

I am now trying to solve the following question:

Suppose $L$ and $K$ are number fields, $K\subset L$, $\Gamma$ is the order of $L$, $O\subset O_K$ is the inverse image of $\Gamma$ via the the inclusion of $K\subset L$. Can we conclude that $\Gamma\otimes_O O_K$ is a subring of $O_L\otimes_O O_K$?

This is deduced to consider if $O_K$ is flat over $O$. Note that $O$ is not Dedekind, it seems not easy to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given by Exercise 1.2.10 in Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*:

> Let $A$ be an integral domain and $B$ its integral closure in the field of fractions $\mathrm{Frac}(A).$ Suppose that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module. Show that $B$ is flat over $A$ if and only if $B = A$. One can show this result is true without the assumption of finiteness of $B$ over $A$.

Though I, too, am at a loss as to how to complete this exercise...

Comment: $B$ is integral over $A$ and $A \rightarrow B$ is injective so $\mathrm{Spec}\,B$ is onto $\mathrm{Spec}\,A$, so $B$ is faithfully flat over $A$. As $B \subset \mathrm{Frac}(A)$, $B \otimes_A \mathrm{Frac}(A)=\mathrm{Frac}(A)$, and therefore the product $B \otimes B \rightarrow \mathrm{Frac}(A)$ is injective. It follows that $b \in B \longmapsto b\otimes 1\in B \otimes B$ is an isomorphism, so that $(B/A) \otimes B=0$, thus $B=A$.